# Decorating a callback

Tags: python, inheritance

The title is probably misleading - but I can't come up with anything better than "what's an elegant way to solve this?"

I have a base class which gets a callback. The callback is used like so:

```
class BaseClass(object):

    def __init__(self, callback, *args, **kwargs):
        self.callback = callback

    def useful_method(self):
        do_something()
        do_more_stuff()

        self.callback()
```

So far so good. Now I want to inherit from that class, and what I want to do is I want to do something equivalent to this:

```
class MyClass(BaseClass):

    def useful_method(self):
        do_something()
        do_more_stuff()

        if self.condition and self.callback():
            self.condition = False
```

I want to avoid duplicating the entire body of `useful_method` prior to the callback call. I cannot make a conditional `super` call in `useful_method`, because the condition is only generated in the calls to `do_something()` and `do_more_stuff()`. What's an elegant way out of this?

EDIT: Assuming I cannot edit the base class.

Comment: There is one obvious answer: modify the base class, i.e. split `BaseClass.useful_method` into two methods, so that you can override one of them.

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot modify the base class, you can modify the `callback` to be *conditional*, something like:

```
class MyClass(BaseClass):

    def __init__(self, callback, *args, **kwargs):
        self.condition = False  # initialize as False/True in dependence of your use case
        self._callback = callback
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(self.conditional_callback, *args, **kwargs)

    def conditional_callback(self):
        if self.condition and self._callback():
            self.condition = False
```

That way anything that would call `self.callback()` *upstream* will act as if it was executing the condition first instead of the callback.